# Is "something red" an example of ellipsis or adjectival positioning

Tags: adjective-position, predicate-adjectives

I want to better understand why the construction *something + [adjective]* makes grammatical sense.

Background: I was recently reading a Washington Post article and came across the following sentence.

> So if you fall in that category, [the movie] feels more like magic than repetitive.

*(Note: I've copied the relevant spoiler-free sentence above; following the link to the article will open you up to movie spoilers! [Source](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/comic-riffs/wp/2015/12/21/star-wars-the-force-awakens-warm-tribute-to-the-1977-original-or-cold-hard-copying/))*

The phrase *more like magic than repetitive* struck me as odd, presumably because it was non-parallel (*more like [noun] than [adjective]*). I would have expected "...more like magic than something repetitive." (Actually, that needs to be rewritten to flow better, but the point is that at least it appears to be grammatical.) Thus, one would have the noun phrase "something repetitive," of the form "[noun] [adjective]."

This got me to thinking about the use of adjectives after nouns. There is a great Stack Exchange article
[here (When can an adjective be postponed)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91664/when-can-an-adjective-be-postposed) that involves the characteristics of the *adjective* that indicate it should come after the noun. But I haven't been able to find examples of how the word "something" requires a postponed adjective.

Consider the following sentences:

> I want to buy something red.
>
> I am looking for something sweet to eat.

You cannot say:

> *I want to buy red something.
>
> *I am looking for sweet something to eat.

But you *can* say:

> I want to buy something (that is) red.
>
> I am looking for something (that is) sweet to eat.

So, my question:

1. Do the above examples mean that the "something [adjective]" construction is an example of the ellipsis of "that is"?
2. Is there something special about the word "something" that requires the postponed adjective? Note that I am NOT looking for details about adjectives that are postponed; I'm interested in the word that precedes the adjective (either "something" or similar words).

By the way, I am *not* interested in the following constructions, which are different:

> I want to paint the house *red*.
>
> I tried to build the brick house *taller*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it's because *I want to buy something red = **I want to buy some red thing***. But since *some* is a determiner (as ***a, the, that***), we know for sure we can't stick the adjective *before* it. *I want to buy red the thing* definitely doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“Something” is a compound determinative. There is a constraint on the position of certain modifiers called 'restrictors' that can be used to modify such compounds. The restrictors (adjectives or certain nominals) cannot occur in pre-head position because of the fused nature of the construction and are forced into post-head position, with only "else" allowed between them and the head:

“Nothing (else) significant”; "everything gold", "somewhere beautiful”, "nowhere special", "somebody rich".

Comment: This is a great answer and exactly the kind of thing that I was looking for. Do you have a source regarding compound determinatives? I see a few entries for determinative compounds ("A type of compound in which part of it gives information that pertains to the compound's head, but not by acting as a modifier"), but the examples given (footstool, armchair) don't appear to be the same class of word. Can you point me in the direction where I can do more research? Thanks!

Comment: Nonnal Do you by any chance have access to The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language (CGEL) by Huddleston & Pullum?

Comment: Ah, if only I did! But sadly, no. If you have extra copies or $250 to spare, though, I'll send you my mailing address. ;-) And owe you a cup of coffee.

Comment: @Nonnal  I can certainly email you the relevant pages, if you like. Assuming it's not breaking any ELU rules, of course.

Comment: would greatly appreciate that. my gmail account has the same username as here, if you would be so kind.

Comment: Thanks again, @BillJ, for the answer and the reference. After review I concur with your analysis and find that this is exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated, especially with your going the extra mile to help me with the source material. Wonderful support, both for me personally and the community at large!

Comment: @Araucaria  Done!

Answer (score 2):

It's both ellipsis (via [*Whiz*-Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/15299)), **and** adjective positioning.

***Something*** is a compound of the indefinite quantifier *some* and the generic neuter noun *thing*.

Quantifiers are determiners, and determiners precede adjectives, and adjectives precede nouns.
So any adjective like *red* would have to appear between *some* and *thing*; i.e, ***some red thing**.*

But *something* is glued together, so *red* has to go after it; i.e, ***something red***.

This is exactly right for a [reduced relative clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20%22reduced%20relative%20clause%22) construction, i.e, ***something (that is) red***.

What all this means is that using an adjective after a noun is not just a matter of adjectives

> -- except a few, like *galore*, which must follow any noun and can't be a predicate adjective --
>
> - *There were costumes galore at the ball.*
> - **There were galore costumes at the ball.*
> - **The (number of) costumes at the ball was/were galore*.

but rather a matter of the constructions involved.

If an adjective can be interpreted as a predicate in a reduced relative clause, it can go after a noun.
Contrariwise, using an adjective after a noun marks it as a predicate in a reduced relative clause.