# Though we use adjectives before nouns normally, why are some words exceptions like 'something'? Why do we use the adjectives after them?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

For example:
something , everything, anything, nothing ... special

someone , everyone , anyone,, no one ... special

somebody , everybody , anybody , nobody ...special

Comment: A special something? A special somebody? Your post makes no sense.

Comment: I believe it is an ellipsis of *something/someone/etc **(that/which is)** special/etc*

Comment: I think your question is the same as this one about [something red](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295735/is-something-red-an-example-of-ellipsis-or-adjectival-positioning). Have a look.

Comment: Here's a suggestion to (maybe) improve this question:  Ask us why is it "something wicked this way comes" versus "a wicked something this way comes" and likewise "a wicked wind is blowing" versus "a wind wicked is blowing."

Comment: This other question, [When can I postpose an adjective and when is it imperative?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91664/when-can-an-adjective-be-postposed) is probably relevant too.

Answer (score 3):

Items like “something”, "everything", "nowhere" etc. are compound determinatives. There is a constraint on the position of certain modifiers called 'restrictors' that can be used to modify such compounds. The restrictors (adjectives or certain nominals) cannot occur in pre-head position because of the fused nature of the construction and are forced into post-head position, with only "else" allowed between them and the head:

"Nothing (else) significant"; "everything gold", "somewhere beautiful", "nowhere special", "somebody rich" and the like.

Answer (score 1):

All those compound words with -one/-body/-thing are pronouns, indefinite pronouns, and an adjective after them is a normal strucure such as

- something beautiful, something interesting.

You can make such structures plausible if you think of shortened relative clauses

- something that is interesting > something interesting.

Indefinite pronouns [Link](http://www.k12reader.com/term/indefinite-pronouns/)

Adjectives [Link](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/English_Grammar/Basic_Parts_of_Speech/Adjectives)

Comment: Please edit your post to follow our [Help Center's guidelines on how to reference other sites](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). It is not sufficient to include merely a link, because the source of the quotation must be able to survive a plain-text (or plain-paper) transformation intact without loss of information explaining who said it and where it's from.