# Omitting which is?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, whiz-deletion

When I was writing an essay, I thought about saying:

> "There is nothing **that is** more important than . . ."

, then I googled it, but it appears the following sentence is more popular.

> "There is nothing more important than . . ."

**Can we always omit "which/that/who/etc. is" when the word that follows it is either an adjective or a participle??**

Comment: Related: [What is a noun modifying clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50962), [Is “something red” an example of ellipsis or adjectival positioning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295735)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is complicated because your sentence contains 2 topics:

1. relative clause
2. some + thing(s)

---

First, "that is", which is a subject pronoun + a verb, can be omitted for this case.

For example:

There is a dog (which is) happy.

-> There is a dog happy.

->> There is a happy dog.

---

Secondly, "something" is an article "some" + noun(s), this "some" acts the same as other articles for this case. But when "thing" that follows the article "some" is without an "s", they become "something" instead of "some thing"

For example:

There is a dog.

-> There is a good dog.

There are some things. ("some" = article)

-> There are some good things.

There is some thing. ("some" = article)

-> There is something

->> There is some good thing.

->>> There is some thing (which is) good.

->>>> There is something good.