# Whats the meaning of "body proper"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

what is the meaning of it in the following sentence:

> These feelings are, in all likelihood, the primordial constituents of mind, based on direct signaling from the **body proper**.

Comment: What research have you done? Have you googled "body proper"? I did and I feel like it would help you.

Comment: Related and possible duplicates: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/91664 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/42319

Answer (score 0):

Per the *OED*, the word *proper* comes to us through Middle English via French and ultimately from the Latin *proprius*, meaning one's own or particular to. The same root gives *property* (something of one's own) and *appropriate* (to take for oneself). When the adjective follow its noun, as in your example, it signals the strict, accurate use of the noun. This is a fairly old usage: the *OED* attests to this use in print around 1400, only a century after its first appearance.

Your excerpt is from [*Self Comes to Mind: Constructing the Conscious Brain*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PBH40-TgBCgC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=These%20feelings%20are,%20in%20all%20likelihood,%20the%20primordial%20constituents%20of%20mind,%20based%20on%20direct%20signaling%20from%20the%20body%20proper.&source=bl&ots=L-PNU8O24g&sig=HTF-hMYmcs8q3I2z-PYOdwwQ-0Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRoqbig4TSAhUKxVQKHUcOB8cQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=These%20feelings%20are%2C%20in%20all%20likelihood%2C%20the%20primordial%20constituents%20of%20mind%2C%20based%20on%20direct%20signaling%20from%20the%20body%20proper.&f=false) by Antonio Damasio, which deals the so-called *mind-body duality*. That is, the feeling we all have that our abstract mental processes (consciousness, sentience, feelings, etc.) have an existence independent from the brain,  a concrete organ of the physiological, of only neurochemistry.

As Damasio puts it

> The properties of minds, let alone conscious minds, appear to be so radically different from those of visible living matter that thoughtful folk wonder how one process (conscious minds working) meshes with the other process (physical cells living together in aggregates called tissues).

In the section of the book from which your excerpt is taken, Damasio is talking about the origin of feelings (which he calls "constituents of the mind and elsewhere "aspects of the mind"). These, he claims, originate from neurochemical processes in parts the brain stem, a part of the *body*, interpreting that word strictly to mean the biochemistry of cellular tissue.